# Use the specific timezone instead of the hosting server timeone

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
  DateTime serverTime = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime servereDate = DateTime.Today;
            DateTimeOffset localTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(serverTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "Singapore Standard Time");
            DateTimeOffset localTime1 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(servereDate, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "Singapore Standard Time");
  if (localTime1.Date >= eddate.Date && localTime1.Date <= stdate.Date)
            {
                if (localTime >= sttime && localTime <= edtime)
                {

                    MySqlConnection MyConn2 = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection2);
                    MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(query, MyConn2);
                    MySqlDataReader MyReader2;
                    MyConn2.Open();
                    MyReader2 = MyCommand2.ExecuteReader();
                    Label2.Text = "Thank you for You Vote";
                  //  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    Label2.Text = "Please check the eletion time!";
                    Label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Label2.Text = "Please check the eletion date!";
                Label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            }
```

I'm trying to get the date in the timezone that I specified(Singapore Standard Time) and compare it with the date I displayed in gridview. I'm able to use the Singapore Standard Time when validating the time. However, for the date, It still not able to get the date in Singapore Standard Time.

Comment: Usually, one would store the times in UTC and use `DateTime.UtcNow` instead of `DateTime.Now`. Then you are independent of any time zone. If you need to use time zones, use `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime`.

Comment: You should always run your database servers in universal time, saves a lot of hassle when you add timestamps on the server.  The values that are returned from the server should contain the offset for its time zone, using the example below should let you compare apples with apples

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to set the specific timezone on my application side. I was able to get the current time for the specific timezone, however for the date, I'm not able to get the correct date in the current timezone.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the dates into universal time for comparison;

```
        DateTime time = DateTime.Today.ToUniversalTime();
        DateTime time2 = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();

        Console.WriteLine(time.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(time2.ToString());
```

The DateTime.Today will return the start of the day in your local time, then convert it to UTC, the DateTime.Now will return the current time and convert it to UTC, these values will only be equal at exactly midnight.

You didn't include the code where you get eddate and stdate, but adding .ToUniversalTime() should do the trick.

If you want everything in local time, you can use .ToLocalTime()

Comment: Why not simply `DateTime.UtcNow`?

Comment: You can use DateTime.UtcNow for the current time, still need DateTime.Today.ToUniversalTime() for the start of the day.   The values returned from the server will need the .ToUniversalTime() if they are returned in another timezone

Comment: But `DateTime.Today.ToUniversalTime()` is the start of the day only for the local time zone (expressed in UTC). There is no universal "start of the day".

Comment: True, start of the day should be from the perspective of the users or from the UTC perspective..   for example the guys in my office want to know what has come in today, from their point of view today starts at midnight local time, for a global bidding system I would user midnight UTC, so that we have a fixed point of reference for everyone.

Comment: Best solution is to make everything is stored in UTC, when the user makes a request in their local time, you convert the request to UTC, do the lookup, then convert the dates in the results back to the users local time to display the results to them.

Comment: Hi, I'm using the .ToLocalTime() since I want everything in local time but it didn't work. It still using the server time.

Comment: Can you share the code you use to get the time values from the server?   By server I assume that you mean the database

Answer (score 0):

Get the client timezone offset from UTC in minutes via a JavaScript if possible and handle the offset with TimeZoneInfo class.

It is the local time zone of the computer that code is running on. In an ASP.Net application, the code runs on the server - so that's the time zone that it will return. So that's why ToLocalTime(), ToUniversalTime() will not fecth you expected results.

Comment: Hi, I'm using the ToLocalTime() but it still using the server timezone. Any idea on how to use the local timezone? I would like to specify the local time is MYT timezone which is UTC+8

Comment: ToLocalTime() won't help you as it will still take server's local time. Best solution is through client-side or the one Xavier mentioned in comments for the server side.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to set the specific timezone on my application side. I was able to get the current time for the specific timezone, however for the date, I'm not able to get the correct date in the current timezone.